# Is wordpress SEO friendly url works without using htaccess?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Wordpress uses friendly seo url without using htaccess.

Can any explain this to me please how they do it.

The only way i can think of is to do something like this.

domain.com/index.php/nnn/mmmm/

But wordpress does not use index.php

I know they are not using htaccess.

Please let me know.

Thank you.

Comment: Yes, Wordpress uses .htaccess files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

WordPress actually has a single .htaccess file that they don't need to change which redirects **all** requests to index.php

index.php then looks at the permalinks rules and runs a few database queries to determine which page to send you.

So for instance if the permalink rule is `%postdate%/%postname%` (may not be the actual WordPress permalink variables. I haven't been using WordPress for too long) then it would just use regular expressions (or combinations of `substr()` and `strpos()`) to put `%postdate%` and `%postname%` into variables. Next it runs a simple database query for any item matching that date and that name. If nothing is found, redirect to search. If you find more than one, list them all (like a category page). If you find one and only one, send that page.

As far as actually "sending" the page, that's just a matter of settings certain variables (such as `$the_post['content']`) and then `include()`'ing the proper theme file.

`include()`'ing the theme file is a simple `if()` statement.

```
if(file_exists("wp-content/themes/<your_theme>/$the_post['type'].php")){
    include("wp-content/themes/<your_theme>/$the_post['type'].php");
} else {
    include("wp-content/themes/<your_theme>/index.php");
}
```

Mind you these aren't the exact variable names or the exact functions as they occur. This is just a very simplified version to give the general idea of how these systems work.

Comment: Can you please tell me where is the .htaccess file is base as i can't seem to find it. I have check box to show all hiden and system files but still i can't seem to see it.

Comment: Also where does wordpress see if this is the catgory or post or page.

Comment: for e.g. on index.php page normally people use the switch where they pass variable and if it match the case then that page is showen.  where does the wordpress does this

Comment: What Operating System is your web server running? If you're running any *nix based system you have to use `ls -a` to see the .htaccess file, and it will be in the WordPress root. If you're running Windows it should be visible at all times if you aren't hiding file extensions. I don't know what happens if you hide the file extension, though.

Comment: I can't seem to find it on my PC but i have find on my ftp.

Comment: Do you know where does wordpress check to see url of the link

Comment: for e.g. domian.com/mmm/mmm/   ... can you please let me know where does it check for mm/mm/ ...

Comment: @Majid - Go to the wordpress admin page (wp-admin) in the left menu, find and click "Settings" after the page loads, find "Permalinks" under Settings submenu. In the next page, you should be able to change the url structure to a predefined one (eh; months/days/etc) or a custom one.

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress does use .htaccess files. You can modify the permalinks in the permalinks section your wordpress site.  You can see information on it [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks).

If you are using IIS you can use [this](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks#Permalinks_without_mod_rewrite) method

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress does actually use .htaccess. Make sure you have hidden files displayed! If you're FTP-ing, there'll be a setting in your client.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the main question:

## No.

As for the other points of yours:

> ## **Wordpress uses friendly seo url without using htaccess.**

***USUALLY* it does not.**

***USUALLY*** it requires the .htaccess to make nice urls work.

**However**, as Wordpress' Codex says:

> If you are using IIS 7 and have admin rights on your server, you can
> use **[Microsoft's URL Rewrite Module](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/460/using-url-rewrite-module/)** instead. Though not
> completely compatible with mod_rewrite, **it does support WordPress's
> pretty permalinks.**

So they are always using some kind of *rewrite module* anyway.

> ## **Can any explain this to me please how they do it.**

There is **one interesting thing** to explain:

- **There is only one .htaccess file.**
- Which would not be so interesting if it would contain some kind of general rule rewriting urls to some.php's GET parameters <strike>(domain.com/verynice => domain.com/index.php?page=verynice)</strike>.
- But **that is not happening**.

What is happening is that

***It [rewrites](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) ANY url that is NOT a specific FILE or DIRECTORY to index.php EXCEPT the index.php*** (to prevent infinite loop).

So urls like `domain.com/blah/blah` and `domain.com/lol/trololo` are both actually requesting the index.php - the only *difference is in the requested URI*.

Using [superglobal variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php) like **`$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`** they **get the requested URI** and after that they **parse the requested URI** and **store the results in varibles accordingly**.

> ## The only way i can think of is to do something like this.
>
> ## domain.com/index.php/nnn/mmmm/

In *common* explanation of the URL this is NOT request to the index.php file itself.

It is a request for the "`mmmm`" folder in folder "`nnn`" which is in folder "`index.php`".

*However* **apache usually understand this as a request for the index.php file** .

For other files e.g. `my.file` `domain.com/my.file` is a file request, `domain.com/my.file/` is a folder request (notice the slash `/` at the end)

> ## But wordpress does not use index.php

That is **NOT TRUE**.

*Especially* if you are using nice-urls the **`index.php` is practicaly fundamental** for Wordpress.

> ## I know they are not using htaccess.

This point of yours could meant 3 things:

1. They *are using* the htaccess but not for processing the URL (which I've explained above)
2. They are not using it at all - not true, unless they would be using the [MS' URL Rewrite Module](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/460/using-url-rewrite-module/)
3. You don't know. You did not provide any information about how did you find out they are not using it, so we can't know if you really know or you just think that :)

> ## Please let me know.

I let you know. And I hope I've answered all your questions :), if not - use comments :)

> ## Thank you.

You are welcome.

I was happy to help :) ☺ ☺ ☺ ☺ ☺